# Show the value from the nearest timestamp from another table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, timestamp

So I have a table called `dash` with two columns: `value` and `date`.
I have a `timestamp` variable called `localtime`.

Both `localtime` and `date` are in `yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm` format. 
I need to find the closest timestamp on `dash`, return the `value`.

Right now what I have doesn't work.

```
def convValueChecking(cursor, localtime):
        cursor.execute("SELECT Value, MIN(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, DATE, %s)) FROM dash", (localtime))

        value = cursor.fetchall()
```

Update: 
This one seems to work, the order_date > locatime is very important, otherwise it looks for the smallest negative number

```
cursor.execute(
        "SELECT order_value, order_date FROM dashboard \
        WHERE order_date > %s\
        ORDER BY ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, %s, order_date))\
        LIMIT 1", (localtime, localtime,))
```

Comment: is this in any way related to Python?

Comment: @ErikAllik Not really

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the SQL string with:

```
SELECT 
  value 
FROM 
  dash
WHERE
  TIMEDIFF(Date, %s) IN 
  (
  SELECT
    MIN(TIMEDIFF(Date, %s))
  FROM
    dash
  )
```

MySQL syntax means you need to do `SELECT` then `FROM` and then declare the `WHERE` part.

`TIMEDIFF` works out the difference between two timestamps. `TIMESTAMPDIFF` works out the difference between two parts of a timestamp (eg between the months, days, seconds etc.). If you want the closest date you should use `TIMEDIFF` to work out the smallest difference overall.

NB. The words `Value` and `Date` also have special properties in MySQL, so you may want to change your column name.

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0abc/4).

Comment: Thank you, now I have : cursor.execute(
        "SELECT order_value FROM dash WHERE TIMEDIFF(order_date, %s) = MIN(TIMEDIFF(order_date, %s))", (localtime, localtime,))            and it's saying I have syntax error

Comment: Yes, your first solution has mysql syntax error. The second solution you provide, MIN() will look for the smallest, and most negative number. I figured something, thank you very much for your help.